# How to display only a range between 2 different months in primeng calendar (p-calendar)?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, calendar, primeng

I'm trying to display a range between 2 months in p-calendar without success for example I would like to display dates only between the middle of a month untile the middle of next month.
I would like to do it using reactiveForm with formcontrol, but a solution with ngModel would be in any case appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking for 2 months blended together?

Answer (score 0):

I am confused what you are asking, but this is a try.  This displays two months allowing for selection of a date range:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Calendar } from 'primeng/calendar';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
<div class="p-fluid p-grid p-formgrid">
  <div class="p-field p-col-12 p-md-4">
    <label for="multiplemonths">Multiple Months</label>
    <p-calendar #rangeCal [(ngModel)]="rangeDates" [numberOfMonths]='2'
      selectionMode="range" inputId="multiplemonths"></p-calendar>
  </div>
</div>`
})
export class AppComponent { 
  @ViewChild( 'rangeCal' ) rangeCal: Calendar;
  rangeDates: Date[];
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```